# Who verbally uses the title "Miss" with a female's first name (regardless of the female's correct title) and why?

Tags: proper-nouns, honorifics

Who verbally uses the title "Miss" with a female's first name (regardless of the female's correct title) and why? Example:

> Meet with Miss Debbie in the conference room at 2 o'clock.

Comment: One of my clients' staff in Texas uses that title for all female staff members.  They address me as "Miss Kristina" when I call.  Maybe it's a regional practice?

Comment: Born and raised in New England, the only people who I referred to as Miss FirstName were my kindergarden teacher (Miss Denise) and my dance teacher (Miss Lisa). The latter is a pretty common practice and I think it's akin to calling a coach Coach X. However, if by some chance you see an episode of *Toddlers & Tiaras* you will see everyone from bedazzled four year olds to octogenarian stage coaches referred to as Miss Brandy, Miss Crystal etc... It's a much more common practice in the American South.

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you want to know the regional variety that does this? Or do you want to know the relation that says this? (boss, employee, someone in lower or higher, very close friends, only relatives, people who are neither friends or relatives, students, what?). Or something else?

Comment: Can you give some context?

Answer (score -1):

In the UK, I think it would be regarded as rather old-fashioned, even Victorian (19th century).